# Converting datetime2 to int

Tags: sql, datetime, type-conversion, integer, datetime2

I want to convert my datetime2 column to int for each record. How do I do it without creating a variable?

Examples of my datetime2 field:

```
2020-03-03 10:17:26.0000000
2020-03-03 10:37:35.0000000
etc...
```

Comment: (1) What integer do you want?  (2) What database are you using?

Comment: Can you show us your desired result from this two dates you have in your question ?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: hi folks, apologies, i am using SSMS, the int i would want would be a whole number in asc order based off of the earliest timedate field. so for example, the earliest date in my query = '2020-03-03 10:37:35.0000000' i would want the int to have any value as logn as it is the lowest value, so it would be 1 or it could be 50, as long as there is no int lower than that value,

Comment: i had tried using SecV's approach, but i get repeating int values

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should specify the sql variant you are using.
Assuming Microsoft T-SQL, you can use the builtin function `CAST`.

```
CAST ( expression AS data_type [ ( length ) ] )
```

In your case, to convert from date to integer, you can simply do:

```
CAST ( [field to convert] AS int )
```

Microsoft reference documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by @HoneyBadger, the direct conversion is not allowed. Since the data doesn't have fractional seconds, you can first try to convert to `datetime` type, and then to `int` (this is allowed):

```
    CAST (CAST ([field to convert] AS datetime) AS int)
```

Comment: `Explicit conversion from data type datetime2 to int is not allowed.`

Comment: thanks for your response, i have tried that but i would have repeating int values. is there a way to have the int value unique and in a asc order based off of my datetime2 field?

Comment: example of my line of results: 2020-03-03 10:37:35.0000000 43891, 2020-03-03 11:03:40.0000000, 43891. as you can see, two different times but they both have the same int value

Comment: That's right, because the int part is corresponding to the days, and the decimal part corresponds to the fraction of a day (hours, minutes, seconds ...). If you want different values for different times, you can cast to a `float`, and then you can anyway sort on that float value